# Why does my program keep getting stuck while running the mandelbrot brainf*** program?

Tags: c, interpreter, mandelbrot, brainfuck

I wanted to improve my C skills, so I search some program's ideas.

Someone propose to create a simple Brainf*** interpreter and then a compiler. So here I am.

I created the interpreter and it works as expected, except with the Mandelbrot program:

```
A mandelbrot set fractal viewer in brainfuck written by Erik Bosman
+++++++++++++[->++>>>+++++>++>+<<<<<<]>>>>>++++++>--->>>>>>>>>>+++++++++++++++[[
>>>>>>>>>]+[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>-]+[>>>>>>>>[-]>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>[-]+
<<<<<<<+++++[-[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>]>>>>>>>+>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
>+<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[-]+[>>>>>>[>>>>>>>[-]>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>
>>>>>[-]+<<<<<<++++[-[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>]>>>>>>+<<<<<<+++++++[-[->>>
>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>]>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[[-]>>>>>>[>>>>>
>>[-<<<<<<+>>>>>>]<<<<<<[->>>>>>+<<+<<<+<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>
[>>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>+<<+<<<+<<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<
<<]>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>+<<+<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>+++++++++++++++[[
>>>>>>>>>]+>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>-]+[
>+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>->>>>[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+<<<<<[->>[
-<<+>>]<<[->>+>>+<<<<]+>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<
<<[>[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<<<<<<<<<<]>[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<
[>[-]<->>>>[-<<<<+>[<->-<<<<<<+>>>>>>]<[->+<]>>>>]<<<[->>>+<<<]<+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>
>>>>[>+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>->>>>>[-<<<<<+>>>>>]<<<<<[->>>>>+
<<<<<<[->>>[-<<<+>>>]<<<[->>>+>+<<<<]+>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>>>>>>[>>
>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>>[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<<<<<<<<<<<]>>[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<<
+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>[-]<->>>>[-<<<<+>[<->-<<<<<<+>>>>>>]<[->+<]>>>>]<<<[->>>+<<
<]<+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>[-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>>>
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>]>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>+++++++++++++++[[>>>>
>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<-<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>-]+>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>+<<<[<<<<<<
<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>[-<<<->>>]+<<<[->>>->[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<
<<<<]>>>>[-]+>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>+<]]+>>>>[-<<<<->>>>]+<<<<[->>>>-<[-<<<+>>>]<<<[->
>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[-]+>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>[-]+<]]+>[-<[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<
<<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]<<<<<<<[->+>>>-<<<<]>>>>>>>>>+++++++++++++++++++
+++++++>>[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+<<[-]<<]>>[<<<<<<<+<[-<+>>>>+<<[-]]>[-<<[->+>>>-
<<<<]>>>]>>>>>>>>>>>>>[>>[-]>[-]>[-]>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[-]>>>>>>[>>>>>
[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+<<<+<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>[-<<<<<<<<
<+>>>>>>>>>]>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>+++++++++++++++[[>>>>>>>>>]+>[-
]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>-]+[>+>>>>>>>>]<<<
<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>->>>>>[-<<<<<+>>>>>]<<<<<[->>>>>+<<<<<<[->>[-<<+>>]<
<[->>+>+<<<]+>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>[->>>>
>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<<<<<<<<<<]>[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>[-]<->>>
[-<<<+>[<->-<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>]<[->+<]>>>]<<[->>+<<]<+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>[-<
<<<<+>>>>>]<<<<<[->>>>>+<<<<+<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>+>>>>>>>>
]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>->>>>>[-<<<<<+>>>>>]<<<<<[->>>>>+<<<<<<[->>[-<<+
>>]<<[->>+>>+<<<<]+>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>
[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<<<<<<<<<<]>[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>[-
]<->>>>[-<<<<+>[<->-<<<<<<+>>>>>>]<[->+<]>>>>]<<<[->>>+<<<]<+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>
[>>>>[-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
]>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>[-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>]>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>++++++++
+++++++[[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<-<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>-]+[>>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<+
>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>+<<<<<<+<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>[
-]>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>+>[-<-<<<<+>>>>>]>[-<<<<<<[->>>>>+<++<<<<]>>>>>[-<
<<<<+>>>>>]<->+>]<[->+<]<<<<<[->>>>>+<<<<<]>>>>>>[-]<<<<<<+>>>>[-<<<<->>>>]+<<<<
[->>>>->>>>>[>>[-<<->>]+<<[->>->[-<<<+>>>]<<<[->>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[-]
+>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>+<]]+>>>[-<<<->>>]+<<<[->>>-<[-<<+>>]<<[->>+<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<
<<<<]>>>>[-]+>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>[-]+<]]+>[-<[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<
[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+>>>>>[>+>>[-<<->>]<<[->>+<<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<
<<<+<[>[->>>>>+<<<<[->>>>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>[->>>+<<<]<]>[->>>-<<<<<<<<<
<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>]<<]>[->>>>+<<<[->>>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>]<]>[->>>+<<<]<<
<<<<<<<<<<]>>>>[-]<<<<]>>>[-<<<+>>>]<<<[->>>+>>>>>>[>+>[-<->]<[->+<]>>>>>>>>]<<<
<<<<<+<[>[->>>>>+<<<[->>>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>[->>>>+<<<<]>]<[->>>>-<<<<<<<
<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>]<]>>[->>>+<<<<[->>>>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>]>]<[->>>>+<<<<
]<<<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>+<<<<<<]]>>>>[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<
[>[->>>>>+<<<<[->>>>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>[->>>+<<<]<]>[->>>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
+>>>>>>>>>>>]<<]>[->>>>+<<<[->>>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>]<]>[->>>+<<<]<<<<<<<
<<<<<]]>[-]>>[-]>[-]>>>>>[>>[-]>[-]>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>[-<
<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+<<<+<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>+++++++++++++++[
[>>>>>>>>>]+>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>-]+
[>+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>->>>>[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+<<<<<[->>
[-<<+>>]<<[->>+>+<<<]+>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<
<[>[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<<<<<<<<<<]>[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[
>[-]<->>>[-<<<+>[<->-<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>]<[->+<]>>>]<<[->>+<<]<+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[
>>>[-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>]>
>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>[-]>>>>+++++++++++++++[[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<-<<<<<
<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>-]+[>>>[-<<<->>>]+<<<[->>>->[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+<<<<<
<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>[-]+>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>+<]]+>>>>[-<<<<->>>>]+<<<<[->>>>-<[-
<<<+>>>]<<<[->>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[-]+>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>[-]+<]]+>[-<[>>
>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[-<<<+>>>]<<<[->>>+>>>>>>[>+>>>
[-<<<->>>]<<<[->>>+<<<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<+<[>[->+>[-<-<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>>[-<<
+>>]<]>[-<<-<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>>]<<<]>>[-<+>>[-<<-<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>>]<]>
[-<<+>>]<<<<<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+>>>>>[>+>>[-<<->>]<<[->>+<<]>>
>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<+<[>[->+>>[-<<-<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>[-<+>]>]<[-<-<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>
>>>>>>>]<<]>>>[-<<+>[-<-<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>]>]<[-<+>]<<<<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>+<<<<<
]>>>>>>>>>[>>>[-]>[-]>[-]>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[-]>[-]>>>>>[>>>>>>>[-<<<<<
<+>>>>>>]<<<<<<[->>>>>>+<<<<+<<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>+>[-<-<<<<+>>>>
>]>>[-<<<<<<<[->>>>>+<++<<<<]>>>>>[-<<<<<+>>>>>]<->+>>]<<[->>+<<]<<<<<[->>>>>+<<
<<<]+>>>>[-<<<<->>>>]+<<<<[->>>>->>>>>[>>>[-<<<->>>]+<<<[->>>-<[-<<+>>]<<[->>+<<
<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>[-]+>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>+<]]+>>[-<<->>]+<<[->>->[-<<<+>>>]<
<<[->>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[-]+>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>[-]+<]]+>[-<[>>>>>>>>>]<
<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[-<<<+>>>]<<<[->>>+>>>>>>[>+>[-<->]<[->+
<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<+<[>[->>>>+<<[->>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>[->>>+<<<]>]<[->>>-
<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>]<]>>[->>+<<<[->>>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>]>]<[->>>+<<<
]<<<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>[-]>>[-<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>+<<+<<<<<]]>>>>[-<<<<+>
>>>]<<<<[->>>>+>>>>>[>+>>[-<<->>]<<[->>+<<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<+<[>[->>>>+<<<[->>>-
<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>[->>+<<]<]>[->>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>]<<]>[->>>+<<[
->>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>]<]>[->>+<<]<<<<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>[-]<<<<]>>>>[-<<<<+>>
>>]<<<<[->>>>+>[-]>>[-<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>+<<+<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>
>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>[->>>>+<<<[->>>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>[->>+<<]<]>[->>-<<<<<<<<
<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>]<<]>[->>>+<<[->>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>]<]>[->>+<<]<<<<<<<<
<<<<]]>>>>>>>>>[>>[-]>[-]>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[-]>[-]>>>>>[>>>>>[-<<<<+
>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+<<<+<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>[-<<<<<+>>>>>
]<<<<<[->>>>>+<<<+<<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>+++++++++++++++[[>>>>
>>>>>]+>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>-]+[>+>>
>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>->>>>[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+<<<<<[->>[-<<+
>>]<<[->>+>>+<<<<]+>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>
[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<<<<<<<<<<]>[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>[-
]<->>>>[-<<<<+>[<->-<<<<<<+>>>>>>]<[->+<]>>>>]<<<[->>>+<<<]<+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>
[>+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>->>>>>[-<<<<<+>>>>>]<<<<<[->>>>>+<<<<
<<[->>>[-<<<+>>>]<<<[->>>+>+<<<<]+>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>
>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>>[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<<<<<<<<<<<]>>[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<<+>>>
>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>[-]<->>>>[-<<<<+>[<->-<<<<<<+>>>>>>]<[->+<]>>>>]<<<[->>>+<<<]<+
<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>[-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>]>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>+++++++++++++++[[>>>>>>>>
>]<<<<<<<<<-<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>-]+>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>+<<<[<<<<<<<<<]
>>>>>>>>>[>>>[-<<<->>>]+<<<[->>>->[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<
]>>>>[-]+>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>+<]]+>>>>[-<<<<->>>>]+<<<<[->>>>-<[-<<<+>>>]<<<[->>>+<
<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[-]+>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>[-]+<]]+>[-<[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<]>
>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>->>[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+<<[-]<<]>>]<<+>>>>[-<<<<
->>>>]+<<<<[->>>>-<<<<<<.>>]>>>>[-<<<<<<<.>>>>>>>]<<<[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>>>[
>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>[-]>>>>]<<<<<<<<<
[<<<<<<<<<]>+++++++++++[-[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>]>>>>+>>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<
<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>+[-]>>[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<
<<<<[>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<+>>>>>>]<<<<<<[->>>>>>+<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>[-]+>>>]<<<<
<<<<<<]]>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>+>>[>+>>>>[-<<<<->>>>]<<<<[->>>
>+<<<<]>>>>>>>>]<<+<<<<<<<[>>>>>[->>+<<]<<<<<<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<
<<<<[>[-]<->>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<+>[<->-<<<+>>>]<[->+<]>>>>>>>]<<<<<<[->>>>>>+<<<<<<]<
+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>-<<<<[-]+<<<]+>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<->>>>>>>]+<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>->>[>>
>>>[->>+<<]>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>[-]<->>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<+>[<->-<<<+>>>]<[->+<]>>>>>>>]<<
<<<<[->>>>>>+<<<<<<]<+<<<<<<<<<]>+++++[-[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>]>>>>+<<<
<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>[-<<<<<->>>>>]+<<<<<[->>>>>->>[-<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>]<<<<
<<<[->>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>[-]+>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>+<]]+>>>>>>>[-<
<<<<<<->>>>>>>]+<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>-<<[-<<<<<+>>>>>]<<<<<[->>>>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<
<<<<<<]>>>[-]+>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>[-]+<]]+>[-<[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<
<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>[-]<<<+++++[-[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>]>>>>-<<<<<[<<<<<<<
<<]]>>>]<<<<.>>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>[-]>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>++++++++++[-[->>>>>>>>
>+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>]>>>>>+>>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<
<<+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>>+[-]>[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<+>>>>>>
>]<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>[-]+>>]<<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>>>>>[-<<<<<
<<<+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>>+>[>+>>>>>[-<<<<<->>>>>]<<<<<[->>>>>+<<<<<]>>>>>>
>>]<+<<<<<<<<[>>>>>>[->>+<<]<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>[-]<-
>>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<<+>[<->-<<+>>]<[->+<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>+<<<<<<<]<+<<<<<<
<<<]>>>>>>>>-<<<<<[-]+<<<]+>>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<<->>>>>>>>]+<<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>>->[>>>
>>>[->>+<<]>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>[-]<->>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<<+>[<->-<<+>>]<[->+<]>>>>>>>>]<<
<<<<<[->>>>>>>+<<<<<<<]<+<<<<<<<<<]>+++++[-[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>]>>>>>
+>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>[-<<<<<<->>>>>>]+<
<<<<<[->>>>>>->>[-<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<
<<]>>>>[-]+>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>+<]]+>>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<<->>>>>>>>]+<<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>>
-<<[-<<<<<<+>>>>>>]<<<<<<[->>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[-]+>>>>>>[>>>>>>
>>>]>[-]+<]]+>[-<[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>[-]<<<++++
+[-[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>]>>>>>->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>-<<<<<<[<<<<
<<<<<]]>>>]
```

I don't understand why, but my program keeps getting stuck in some sort of endless loop. I try to debug it using gdb but it's hard to find the right breakpoint in order to see why it stuck.

The program is as follows:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Brainfuck instructions
//  > Math stuff
#define INCR '+' // +1 on current MS
#define DECR '-' // -1 on current MS
//  > Memory slot stuff
#define FORW '>' // Go to next MS
#define BACK '<' // Go to previous MS
//  > Logic stuff
#define SJMP '[' // Loop till current MS value is equal to zero
#define EJMP ']' // Jump to the beginning of the loop
//  > I/O stuff
#define PRTC '.' // Print character with MS value as ASCII code
#define GETC ',' // Get an user input ASCII character code

typedef unsigned char byte;

// The brainfuck program struct
typedef struct {
      byte *values;
      int size;
      int index;

      byte *loops_starts;
      int loop_size;
      int loop_index;

} BrainfuckProgram;

void initialize(BrainfuckProgram *bfp) {
      bfp->values = malloc(bfp->size * sizeof(*bfp->values));
      bfp->loops_starts = malloc(bfp->size * sizeof(*bfp->loops_starts));
}

int allocate_values(BrainfuckProgram *bfp) {
      byte *newMem = realloc(bfp->values, bfp->size * sizeof(byte));

      if (!newMem) {
            return 1;
      }
      bfp->values = newMem;

      return 0;
}

int allocate_new_loop(BrainfuckProgram *bfp) {
      byte *newMem = realloc(bfp->loops_starts, bfp->loop_size * sizeof(byte));

      if (!newMem) {
            return 1;
      }
      bfp->loops_starts = newMem;

      return 0;
}

void set_value(BrainfuckProgram *bfp, byte value) {
      int tempValue = value < 0 ? 255: value % 256;
      *(bfp->values + bfp->index) = tempValue;
}

int get_value(BrainfuckProgram *bfp) {
      return *(bfp->values + bfp->index);
}

// FILE functions
int get_file_name(int argc, char *argv[], char** fname) {
     if (argc == 1) {
           printf("File name is missing\n");
           return 1;
     }

     *fname = argv[1];
     return 0;
}

int get_file_size(FILE *file) {
    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);
    int size = ftell(file);
    rewind(file);
    return size;
}

// Main function
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
      // Vector part
      BrainfuckProgram bfp = {
            .values = NULL,
            .size = 1,
            .index = 0,

            .loops_starts = NULL,
            .loop_index = 0,
            .loop_size = 0

      };


      initialize(&bfp);

      // FILE Part
    char* fname = NULL;
      int error = get_file_name(argc, argv, &fname);
      if (error) {
            goto exit;
      }

    // Create file variable
    FILE *fin = NULL;
    fin = fopen(fname, "r");

    int size = get_file_size(fin);

    // Create a char array of the right size
    byte *prog = NULL;
    prog = malloc(size * sizeof(*prog));
      // Read 1 byte size times
    fread(prog, 1, size, fin);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            byte current =  *(prog+i);
        switch (current) {
            case INCR:
                        set_value(&bfp, get_value(&bfp) + 1);
                break;

            case DECR:
                        set_value(&bfp, get_value(&bfp) - 1);
                break;

            case FORW:
                        // if index+1 == size then we are at the
                        // last element of the vector cause
                        // size = index - 1
                        if (bfp.index+1 == bfp.size) {
                              bfp.size++;

                              int error = allocate_values(&bfp);
                              if (error) {
                                    printf("an error occured while forwarding pointer");
                                    goto close;
                              }
                        }
                        bfp.index++;

                break;

            case BACK:
                        // bfp.index == 0 then !bfp.index == true
                        if (!bfp.index) {
                             printf("can go back from index 0\n");
                             goto close;
                        }
                        bfp.index--;

                break;

            case SJMP:
                        if (bfp.loop_index == bfp.size) {
                              bfp.loop_size++;

                              int error = allocate_new_loop(&bfp);
                              if (error) {
                                    printf("an error occured while forwarding pointer");
                                    goto close;
                              }

                        }
                        bfp.loop_index++;
                        *(bfp.loops_starts + bfp.loop_index) = i;

                break;

            case EJMP:
                        if (bfp.loop_index == -1) {
                              printf("cannot go back");
                              goto close;
                        }

                        if (get_value(&bfp) != 0) {
                              i = *(bfp.loops_starts + bfp.loop_index);

                        } else {
                              bfp.loop_index--;

                        }

                break;

            case PRTC:
                        printf("%c", get_value(&bfp));

                break;

            case GETC:
                        ; // Semicolon here because of the label error
                        byte buf;
                        scanf("%c", &buf);
                        set_value(&bfp, buf);

                break;

        }
    }

      close:
            fclose(fin);

      exit:
            ;

    return 0;
}
```

I'd like to have some C related advice on what I have done wrong too.

Comment: I think the program is small enough to post it in your question, rather then a link to it.

Comment: Step through your code in a debugger ; or and/or fish with breakpoints while it's running and apparently in the infinite loop

Comment: Post your code here instead of linking to external sites. But first: Reduce the code as much as possible by removing parts that isn't relevant for the question

Comment: I upvote for using proper malloc idiom instead of repeating the type name 3 times like most people seem to do

Comment: can you explain why you write `value < 0 ? 255: value % 256`   when `value` is an unsigned char?

Comment: You probably have realized that brainf*** got its name for a reason... ;-) To debug a program interpreted in another program - if you master this you surely will be very experienced in debugging.

Comment: Mandelbrot is computationally expensive, an interpreter is not ideal.  "Getting stuck" is indistinguishable from "not yet done" when you have no real idea how long the program is supposed to take.  Let it run over-night, sleep on ideas to write a BF compiler.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the Mandelbrot program takes a *long* time to run on a good interpreter. Yours, well, it isn't that good.

Comment: @M.M The input in BrainFuck must be preserved. You can't discard whitespace, it won't work.

Comment: There is something off with allocation in `case SJMP:`. You check the size against `bfp.size`, yet you allocate using `bfp.loop_size`. I guess the `*(bfp.loops_starts + bfp.loop_index) = i` is accessing outside the buffer. Yes, I think you meant to `if (bfp.loop_index == bfp.loop_size)`

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations?

Comment: Hey, people trying to close this: It was fixed after it got the close votes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Mandelbrot program takes a decent time to run on a good interpreter. Yours, well, it isn't that good. That's why it "hangs" at the start.

Some good ideas that you had, performance-wise:

- precalculating loops

Some bad ideas, performance-wise:

- Using abstracted allocation functions instead of calling `realloc`
- using `scanf` and `printf` instead of `getchar` and `putchar`

Some odd things that you did:

- Manually truncating an `unsigned char` when wraparound is implicit
- checking if an `unsigned char` is less than 0
- using `*(x + y)` syntax instead of array indexing `x[y]`
- I don't think you actually use those precalculated loops, if you do then probably not correctly
- You also probably create a new precalculated loop every time you go over the loop again
- Using the `get_value` and `set_value` functions instead of pointers (this will be a performance issue if you don't compile with optimizations)

A couple suggestions:

- Try to avoid calling functions when you don't need to as much as possible.
- Write a BrainFuck->C compiler using [this reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck#Commands).

On second thought, maybe you should try to debug [this program](https://www.linusakesson.net/programming/brainfuck/) instead.

You may also use [my interpreter](https://github.com/JL2210/bf.git) as a reference if you're OK with GPLv3. Note that it doesn't precalculate loops.

Comment: I will try to implement all the advice you gave me, thanks!

Though I have a question, what do you mean by precalculated loop ?

Comment: @ThomasTeixeira `allocate_new_loop` and `loop_index`?